# Beaglebone Black Wireless: UART isn't reading

Tags: python, debian, beagleboneblack, uart

I'm trying to have a Beaglebone Black Wireless(debian image 2017-07-01) communicate to another device using UART serial communication. In an example program, the bone waits for the device to send the letter "A", then, upon receiving the right letter, outputs a message and transmits the letter "B". Here is the following program:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART
import serial

#Enabling the serial ports
UART.setup("UART1")

#Serial setup values
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyO1"
ser.baudrate = 9600  
READ_LEN = 1
ser.close()

rx = ""

while True:
    print "Waiting for A... "
    ser.open()
    rx = ser.read()
    ser.close()

    if (rx == 'A'):
        print "Got it!"
        ser.open()
        ser.write("B")
        ser.close()
        break
```

The program doesn't throw any errors, however, when testing it out with the device, the program gets stuck on the "Waiting for A" line. I have thoroughly checked that all connections are correct and that the other device is sending data. Additionally, the program runs perfectly on an older Beaglebone (debian image 2015-11-12).

Any help into this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

config-pin "Whatever Pin You Are Using" uart

example:

config-pin P9.14 uart

If you update to a current image, the UART pins in the system (Linux) are located in `/dev/bone/uart/*` . So, you can use them in that method.

Also, while others are not strictly dedicating time to update and upgrade Adafruit_BBIO as far as I know, one can use:

1. `sudo apt install python3-serial`
2. `or another UART lib`

The people at beagleboard.org, from what I have noticed, have changed things a bit. I have seen changes in their serial interface in sysfs.

So, for instance, `/dev/ttyS1` would work instead of `/dev/ttyO1`.

Comment: https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/blob/master/doc/run_config-pin_during_startup.md